# "cannot be resolved to a variable" in a cast

Tags: java, decompiling

I decompiled a jar using http://jd.benow.ca/ and I keep getting "PluginResourceLoader cannot be resolved to a variable" at the cast "(PluginResourceLoader)" below in Eclipse.  I set the compiler version to 1.5 since the jar was compiled with 1.5.  It is trying to cast to its own class (a static nested class).

```
public class StandardPluginClassLoader extends PluginClassLoader {
...
  static PluginResourceLoader get(PluginManager paramPluginManager,
    PluginDescriptor paramPluginDescriptor) {
    ...
    //My Test code.  Works
    PluginResourceLoader t = new PluginResourceLoader(null);

    //Generates "PluginResourceLoader cannot be resolved to a variable"
    (PluginResourceLoader)AccessController
        .doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
      public Object run() {
        return new StandardPluginClassLoader
          .PluginResourceLoader((URL[])this.val$urls
          .toArray(new URL[this.val$urls.size()]));
      }
    });
   }
...
}
```

Comment: Why would you cast like that? It's not in code that returns a value, you don't change the behavior of the identifier that follows it, since you don't enclose both in parenthesis. i.e., you don't do `((Foo) bar).baz();`

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, that's the output of the decompiler.

Comment: So, you're asking us to debug code produced by a malfunctioning decompiler? I'm out.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, I can see that such a cast doesn't do anything that's required, but don't understand why it causes that error in recompiling.  An necessary cast shouldn't produce a compile error, unless there's something I'm not seeing.

Comment: @DarkV1, it's from a third party library and the source is no longer available. I'm trying to put it up on Maven Central Repo which requires the source.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's essentially asking us why a third party library, the decompiler, is not working.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, I'm not asking why the decompiler isn't working.  I'm asking why is Eclipse complaining that that cast is an error in the >RECOMPILING< of the code.  I can understand a warning about an unnecessary cast but this is not a warning.

Comment: exactly, but can anyone see the problem based on what you've posted so far?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, I will wait to see if anyone does.  Maybe its a known issue with Eclipse or maybe there is a legitimate reason such code would be a compile error in java that I don't know about.